# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when creating a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So ive searched and can't find a existing question that has helped me with this.

I have a model:

```
class ClassComments < ActiveRecord::Base
 # attr_accessible :title, :body
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :class, :class_name => 'Clas'
end
```

And when I call `c = ClassComments.new` in my controller I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas on what is causing this? I'm stumped!

Comment: You may want to consider a different name than "class" since it is a reserved word in ruby/rails. I assume thats why you have the `:class_name => 'Clas'` but that can become very confusing. http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/

Comment: @JasonTruluck yes thats why i ultimately named the class "clas". Are you saying that this could be causing the issue? Or just a helpful suggestion?

Comment: both actually, could you include your `Clas` model and schema? That may help decipher this a bit. And is the controller just the normal scaffolded one?

Comment: @JasonTruluck went ahead an took your suggestion, the name was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I will add it to the answers for visibility then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the class name to something other than `Clas` or `Class` will fix the issue since class it is a reserved word in ruby/rails.

Source:
http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/

Comment: Changed `belongs_to :class, :class_name => 'Clas'` to `belongs_to :clas`
 and it work perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the foreign key in addition to the class name as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295262/rails-belongs-to-association-with-class-name-returns-nil)

So in your case, it would probably be:

```
belongs_to :class, :class_name => 'Clas', :foreign_key => "clas_id"
```

Comment: Defining the class name should've taken care of that - tried it anyways and it didn't solve the problem.